# No se suscriben usuarios en OneSignal con versiones de android 5 o superiores

Tags: angularjs, ionic, push-notification, onesignal, fcm

Estoy integrando las **notificaciones-push** en mi aplicacion híbrida desarrollada en Ionic v1, pero me he contrado con un problema un poco extraño, y es que los usuarios con versión de android 5 o superior no se están suscribiendo a la plataforma de **OneSignal**.

Tengo un teléfono el cual tiene Android 4.2.2, y funciona todo a la normalidad, se suscribe, y funciona todo. Hace dias, se podía suscribir a un teléfono el cual probaba que tenia Android 6.0.1, pero luego dejo de hacerlo, y lo mismo con Android 5, el cual ya realice la prueba.

#### Pruebas hechas para deducir e problema

- Crear nueva app tanto como en **FCM** tanto como en **OneSignal**,
- Cambiar las respectivas **keys** y el número del nuevo proyecto
  generado en la plataforma
- Cambiar los valores también en el servidor y en el app

Aun así, el problema persiste, no se suscriben a la plataforma.

#### Cambios hechos en la app

- El usuario luego de pasar por una especie de filtro, en donde, se preguntaba si era estudiante o docente, para luego ejecutar la suscripcion, y pasar al menu correspondiente. (Persiste el error para Android 5 o superiores, no hay suscripción)
- Luego, suscribirlos cuando la aplicacion, redireccione al llegar al menú, ya que entonces, la vista estaría siempre activa, y el fichero que contiene el código de suscripción, estaria siempre activo (Persiste el error para Android 5 o superiores).

#### Codigo

```
 // Add to index.js or the first page that loads with your app.
    // For Intel XDK and please add this to your app.js.

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        // Enable to debug issues.
        // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
        
        var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        };

        window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit('862b34cb-f0ba-4ab3-89b7-bf7d84e85162')
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .endInit();
        
        // Call syncHashedEmail anywhere in your app if you have the user's email.
        // This improves the effectiveness of OneSignal's "best-time" notification scheduling feature.
        // window.plugins.OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(userEmail);
    }, false);
```

El código es tomado de la misma guía de **OneSignal**

- [Enlace 1](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk)
- [Enlace 2](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup)

**Nota:** No quiero que la suscripción de realice al momento de inciar la aplicacion, ya que nadie debería recibirlas, si no esta *logueado*.

Comment: Has revisado que mensaje obtiene al intentar obtener el id de registro del dispositivo que entrega google???

Comment: Pues @Jorgesys ni siquiera se suscribe, pero voy a revisar eso de nuevo, a ver que pasa.

Comment: "Si haces un adb logcat ves algún error? Usas la ultima versión del plugin?`"- j0se

Comment: Al parecer no era error del plugin si no la versión sobre la que estaba desarrollando la App, estaba con la versión 1.3, entonces decidí crear un nuevo proyecto, me instalo la version 1.3.2, y rvise el XML del config y vi qu tienen cosas nuevas, y me funciono